# Show or hide Div based on the checkbox value

Tags: jquery

I want to display a div based on the checkbox value. I tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#parent').change(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
    $('#child').css('display', 'block');
}
    else {
    $('#child').css('display', 'none');
}
});
```

});

Now it's working if I check the `#parent` checkbox. But the problem is the checkbox is in a form. Next time I refresh the page,even though the checkbox is checked, it still displays none.

How to checked this displayed if the checkbox is checked or else display none.

Thanks

Comment: you need to evaluate if the checkbox is checked each time the page is loaded

Comment: Trigger the `change` event: `$('#parent').change(fn).change()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger the change event using **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** or **[`trigger('change')`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#child').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $('#child').css('display', 'none');
    }
  }).change();
});
```

---

Also you can reduce the code using **[`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').change(function() {
    $('#child').toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: @Ayanize : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#parent').change(function () {
    if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
        $('#child').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        $('#child').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? `if($(this). prop("checked") == true){` is the less efficient version of  `if (this.checked) {`